# Directive doesn't work when I which the version of Angular to 1.0.1 to 1.2.27

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The following could be run in [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/SPMfT/) here.

this is html:

`<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h2>Parent Scope</h2>
    <input ng-model="foo"> <i>// Update to see how parent scope interacts with component scope</i>

    <br><br>
    <!-- attribute-foo binds to a DOM attribute which is always
    a string. That is why we are wrapping it in curly braces so 
    that it can be interpolated. 
    -->
    <my-component attribute-foo="{{foo}}" binding-foo="foo" 
        isolated-expression-foo="updateFoo(newFoo)" >
        <h2>Attribute</h2>
        <div>
            <strong>get:</strong> {{isolatedAttributeFoo}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>set:</strong> <input ng-model="isolatedAttributeFoo">
            <i>// This does not update the parent scope.</i>
        </div>
        <h2>Binding</h2>
        <div>
            <strong>get:</strong> {{isolatedBindingFoo}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>set:</strong> <input ng-model="isolatedBindingFoo">
            <i>// This does update the parent scope.</i>
        </div>
        <h2>Expression</h2>

        <div>
            <input ng-model="isolatedFoo">
            <button class="btn" ng-click="isolatedExpressionFoo({newFoo:isolatedFoo})">Submit</button>
            <i>// And this calls a function on the parent scope.</i>
        </div>
    </my-component>
</div>`

And this is js:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            /* NOTE: Normally I would set my attributes and bindings
            to be the same name but I wanted to delineate between 
            parent and isolated scope. */                
            isolatedAttributeFoo:'@attributeFoo',
            isolatedBindingFoo:'=bindingFoo',
            isolatedExpressionFoo:'&'
        }        
    };
})
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'Hello!';
    $scope.updateFoo = function (newFoo) {
        $scope.foo = newFoo;
    }
}]);
```

This should be a good example for three kinds of scope binding in directives.However, it just doesn't work when I try to switch a higher angular version - (1.2.27). I suspect the shadow of the inherited scope within the directive, but I'm not sure of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to work the way you expect.  Isolated Scopes are created and provided to the `Link`, `Compile`, and `Template` portions of a Directive.  However, the HTML within the `Element` itself is not actually part of the Directive.  Those HTML portions are still bound to the parent `$scope`.  If you have a tendancy to name your isolated scope objects the same, you may have just been working against the `$scope` unintentionally and not noticed any ill effect.  If your HTML was in a `Template` rather than inside the `Element`, it would access the isolate scope.

As an example, in the HTML that is inline in the `Element`, you can call `updateFoo()`, but that would not be possible from inside a `Template`

Comment: Thanks, Claies, now I know the html element should be put into the template of the directive rather than put under the outside scope. However I think it is possible  to call an expression on the parent scope from the isolated scope (use the & symbol),see this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nUXWrj4yzypaQmtJShl9?p=preview)

Comment: yes, if you just use `&`, then you can pass the function along.  however, in your example, you assigned the function to a different name.  the `ng-click=isolatedExpressionFoo()` didn't work from the HTML page, but does work inside the Template.  By the same token, `ng-click=UpdateFoo()` works in the HTML, but wouldn't work if it were put in the Template.

Comment: Essentially, without a Template and/or Link/Compile functions, you essentially created a Directive that didn't do anything.  Directives can be containers for other Elements, the same way you might put an `<input>` inside a `<div>`, but the items you put in the element in the DOM tree are not actually the directive.

Comment: now I'm more clear about the isolated scope, thank you!

Comment: my recommendation: look into using the controller-as syntax, and eliminating $scope wherever possible.  then, once you have eliminated $scope, look into turning your page elements into Directives as components, and it's possible to have an angular app which never uses $scope or ng-controller (only uses controller assignments on individual directives, and directives each use isolated scope and services exclusively).

Comment: Actually, I'm just doing some optimization on my project, and I've changed my $scope to 'this' according to controller-as syntax, and what I'm doing now is componentize my html, so glad to see your advice, I've another two questions: 1.Many of my 'component' would never be reused, so should it deserve to componentize with directive.2.I see 'without $scope', but how the controller be defined without ng-controller ?, in other words, what's the defect of 'ng-controller' ?thx!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70366/discussion-between-claies-and-yqfang).

Comment: As I'm from China(some website always been blocked), sorry for the delay of my word, anyway, I've understood your advice, really, really thank you :)