# angular directive with isolate scope, fields inaccessible

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to write a directive which takes a scope variable name and assigns to it the result of passing a different named parameter into a function.  Below, the `files="result"` is intended to create a `{{result}}` variable in the `glob` isolate scope.   The contents of the "`matching`" variable are to be evaluated in the parent context, and assigned to an isolate '`matching`' variable.

the directive then calls a function eventually assigning to the isolate variable pointed to by files (`result` here) the array returned.   expansion of `{{result}}` could then be used for example in an `ng-repeat`.

The directive should be reusable without changing the variable names.

This isn't happening.  If I assign everything to a parent, I can get it working but need to change the variable names each time.

```
angular.module('j20-glob', ['api'])
/*
 *  usage: <glob files="result" matching="/bin/{{prefix}}*">
 *            {{result}}
 *         </glob>
 *       should allow another just after the first without stomping result
 *      <glob files="result" matching="/something">{{result}}</glob>
 */

.directive('glob', ['$parse', 'api', function($parse, $api) {
  return {
    priority: 99, // it needs to run after the attributes are interpolated    
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {

    },

    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes) {

       var indexModel = $parse(iAttributes.files);
        iAttributes.$observe('matching', function(value) {
          if (!value)
             return;
          $api.glob(value).then(function(res) {
              indexModel.assign(scope, res);
             // indexModel.assign(scope.$parent, res);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Plunker/Fiddle/CodePen maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code here, you are having a similar issue to what I answered here: [Directive doesn't work when I which the version of Angular to 1.0.1 to 1.2.27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358582/directive-doesnt-work-when-i-which-the-version-of-angular-to-1-0-1-to-1-2-27/28358876#28358876).

You have created an Element Directive, called `glob`.  The Directive has an Isolate Scope, which you attach a property, `result` in your example.  This all works fine.  The problem is, the property in the isolate scope is only accessible within the directive; and in your case, you are trying to access it outside the directive.

The Element `<glob></glob>` is your directive.  This Element can be containers for other Elements, for example an angular expression `{{result}}` but these Elements are not part of the Directive, and therefore not scoped in the isolate.

If you were to include a template, and place `{{result}}` inside the template, you would see the expected result. However, this stops working if you change the variable you are passing in.

A rough draft of a working Directive using a transclude function might be something like:

```
.directive('glob', ['$parse', 'api', function($parse, $api) {
  return {
    priority: 99, // it needs to run after the attributes are interpolated    
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {

    },
    transclude : true,
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, ctrl, transclude) {

       var indexModel = $parse(iAttributes.files);
        iAttributes.$observe('matching', function(value) {
          if (!value)
             return;
          $api.glob(value).then(function(res) {
              indexModel.assign(scope, res);
             // indexModel.assign(scope.$parent, res);
          });
          //append our scope into the DOM element (clone) instead of $scope
          transclude(scope, function(clone, scope){
              element.append(clone);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the effect of the index variable in ng-repeat, for example.
`<ul ng-repeat="i in norm">
   <li>{{i}}</li>
</ul>`
ties up i only while in the directive, no?

I also tried transcluding everything inside the `<glob></glob>` but that doesn't do it either.

Comment: you will most likely have to use transclusion; see http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Comment: the `ng-repeat` directive doesn't use an isolated scope, it creates a child scope.

Comment: and it does use transclusion.  See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c2031b1e9e52ecaa89da5d489941488e62643ff5/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js

Comment: note their link function, accepts the `$transclude` function as the 5th argument, performs their logic, then at the end uses `clone` inside the `$transclude` function to modify the DOM element.